# Javascript binding function to an object

Tags: javascript

```
const person = {
    name: "Mike",
    country: "New Zealand"
}

function personUpdate(name, country) {
    this.name = name
    this.country = country
}

personUpdate.bind(person)

personUpdate('Tony', 'Chile')
```

Why doesn't this work? `person` still has original properties 'Mike' and 'New Zealand'. Why doesn't `personUpdate.bind(person)` I want to make it so that every call to `personUpdate` the `this` refers to the `person` object (and without using `new`).

Comment: var boundPersonUpdate = personUpdate.bind(person); boundPersonUpdate('Tony', 'Chile');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `.bind` doesn't modify the function you pass in; it returns a new bound function.

So you want either:

```
var boundPersonUpdate = personUpdate.bind(person);
boundPersonUpdate(...); // call the bound version
```

or:

```
personUpdate = personUpdate.bind(person); // overwrite the original function
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and I think nothing is wrong with it.

```
const person = {
name: "Mike",
country: "New Zealand"
}
function personUpdate(name, country) {
this.name = name;
this.country = country;

console.log(this.name);
console.log(this.country);
}
personUpdate.bind(person);
personUpdate('Tony', 'Chile');
```

I tried to print it and it is giving me "Tony" and "Chile", or I misunderstood your question?